# Can not ssh to server without a password

Tags: centos, ssh, command, remote

I have two VM machines, and I want them to run a remote command on each other via ssh. I ran these commands on the first machine:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-copy-id 192.168.254.148
```

Then I ran this command and it didn't ask for a password:

```
[root@fazi1 data1]# ssh root@192.168.254.148 df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3       7.7G  893M  6.5G  12% /
tmpfs           1.5G   16K  1.5G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1       194M   41M  144M  22% /boot
/dev/sda2        11G  7.7G  2.4G  77% /data1
/dev/sda7       4.5G  539M  3.8G  13% /data2
/dev/sda5       7.7G  1.4G  6.0G  19% /opt
```

I ran these commands on the second machine:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-copy-id 192.168.254.150
```

And when I wanted to check if it is working or not:

```
[root@fazi2 data1]# ssh root@192.168.254.150 df -h
root@192.168.254.150's password:
```

Why does it work the way I want on the first machine and act different on the second one?

What should I do? (I ran these commands a few times to make sure I didn't enter an incorrect password.)

Comment: It's usually a permissions problem either on the ~/.ssh directory or one of the files.

Comment: @NickD do you mean the rwx? or a configuration inside files?

Comment: What user did you create the keys for on the local system and what user ran `ssh-copy-id`?  There is no indication in the question that this was done by the same user that you're trying to connect as (root). Also, you don't need root to run `df -h`.

Comment: @Kusalananda i ran all the commands by root. that `df -h` was just for test that i don't need password.i figured out the problem and solve it. i describe the problem in comment in Ulrich answer.

Comment: @BlackCrystal Clarifications to the question should go into the question, not be left in comments that very few people read.

Answer (score 4):

If I remember correctly, if root login is disabled on `.150`, i.e. you have

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

in `/etc/sshd/sshd_config`, it will reject all the keys, and possibly fall through to password authentication, if that is in principle allowed. (It will also then reject all passwords, even the correct one.)

Running `ssh -vvv root@192.168.254.150 false` will give you a pretty verbose output of what might go wrong. You'll see lines for your keys in `/root/.ssh/id_rsa` etc.,  and you can see if your client is offering them to the server, and if the server likes them. If you're not offering, it's likely a permission problem on the client side, if the server is rejecting them, they're either not in `authorized_keys` on the remote side (but `ssh-copy-id` should have given you an error then, or the server doesn't permit root logins.

Comment: the PermitRootLogin was yes and -vvv didn't show anything useful. but i finally found the problem. both root passwords on both servers were same. i changed them into something different from each other, it worked. i don't know the reason btw.